# Run multiple commands in a node package file?

Tags: node.js

For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "coffee --watch --compile .; compass watch public/compass"
},
```

How can I get this working, so it compiles my coffescripts and my compass project?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run

**sequential sub-tasks**

If you have 2 tasks you want to run in series, you can just npm run each task separated by a &&:

```
"build": "npm run build-js && npm run build-css"
```

**parallel sub-tasks**

If you want to run some tasks in parallel, just use & as the separator!

```
"watch": "npm run watch-js & npm run watch-css"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. That might be only for commands that finish?

Answer (score 2):

#### Install [parallelshell](https://github.com/keithamus/parallelshell) npm pacakge

```
npm install parallelshell --save-dev
```

#### Use it instead of `&` in your npm script(s)

```
"build": "echo TODO: build the project and start watching",
"serve": "echo TODO: start a development web server",
"start": "parallelshell \"npm start build\" \"npm start serve\""
```

#### Run multiple sub-tasks in parallel (Mac, Linux, Windows)

```
$ npm start
```

--- alternatively ---

Create a .js file that spins multiple processes via Node.js [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Here is an example:

```
"start": "node tools/start.js"
```

Where `tools/start.js` may look like this:

https://github.com/kriasoft/aspnet-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/start.js